# WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, jquery/jquery-plugins.js, from library, primefaces

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

Hello friends I have found this error while running my web application. I am using Primefaces.

**WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, jquery/jquery-plugins.js, from library, primefaces.**

Is there any way to remove this WARNING Message ?

Comment: You should add some code of your view, PrimeFaces version also.

Comment: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7567 ??

Comment: Thank you Alexandre and Orangepill.